# Error running Master PDF Editor 4 - missing libQtSvg.so.4

Tags: pdf, 16.10, qt4

After downloading Master PDF Editor 4 for Linux from the https://code-industry.net website (as a tar.gz) and unarchiving it into /opt, it gives an error when attempting to run it:

```
./masterpdfeditor4: error while loading shared libraries: libQtSvg.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching the web, I found how to install the shared library by installing the package `libqt4-svg`.  However, subsequently running `masterpdfeditor4` caused the error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".  So, I installed some other KDE dependencies and then it launched fine.

(I just did `sudo apt-get install konsole`, but there is likely a way to only install the dependencies it actually needs)

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  konsole konsole-kpart kpackagelauncherqml kpackagetool5
  libkf5declarative-data libkf5declarative5 libkf5kirigami2-5
  libkf5newstuff-data libkf5newstuff5 libkf5newstuffcore5
  libkf5notifyconfig-data libkf5notifyconfig5 libkf5package-data
  libkf5package5 libkf5pty-data libkf5pty5 libkf5quickaddons5 libphonon4qt5-4
  libphonon4qt5-data phonon4qt5 phonon4qt5-backend-vlc
  qml-module-org-kde-kirigami2 qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrolsaddons
  qml-module-org-kde-newstuff qml-module-qtqml-models2
```

Comment: Installing konsole was an easy solution for me. I added the packages that were installed to this answer for anyone who cares to sort out which are relevant to solving the `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error.